# Android - Changing ImageView between two images on button click and reclick

Tags: android, android-imageview

So I have an ImageView that has a certain image resource let's say `image1` and I when I click the image I change it to another image resource called `image2`, what I want is to be able to change it back to `image1` and so on. What I tried is the following and it doesn't work.

```
public void methodName(){
        final ImageView imageNo1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageID);
        Drawable seatDrawable = imageNo1.getDrawable();
        imageNo1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(imageNo1.getDrawable()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1)){
                    imageNo1.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
                } else {
                    imageNo1.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I also tried setting a boolean `currentState` to false and changing it in the if statement after the click, but that didn't work either. So how do I get this to work?

Here's how I used `currentState`

```
public void methodName(){
        private boolean currentState = false;
        final ImageView imageNo1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageID);
        imageNo1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(currentState = false){
                    imageNo1.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
                    currentState = true;
                } else if(currentState = true) {
                    imageNo1.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Solution: Thanks to dhaval for providing the solution with setTag and getTag

Comment: I would rather use the `setTag()` and `getTag()` method to keep track of the current image being displayed

Comment: using currentState is close to the correct answer, how is it not working?

Comment: There is wrong if...else statement, it should be like `if(currentState == false){` and `else if(currentState == true)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this way and it works fine:

```
public void methodName(){
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    imgView.setTag(1);
    imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(imgView.getTag() == 1){
                imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_btn_rating_star_off_mtrl_alpha);
                imgView.setTag(2);
            }else{
                imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_btn_rating_star_on_mtrl_alpha);
                imgView.setTag(1);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: gives me `error: incomparable types: Object and int` on the `imgView.getTag() == 1`

Comment: works fine now after I edited it to `getTag().equals(1)`

Comment: I am testing on Android Studio and Nexus device where it works fine so ideally it should cast implicitly, but have you tried casting it manually like `((int) imgView.getTag()) == 1`

Answer (score 1):

JUST USE if/else IN YOUR CODE:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int a=0;

    public void Here(View view){

    if(a==0)
    {
        ImageView image1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.female);
        a=1;
    }
    else
    {
        ImageView image2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.male);
        a=0;
    }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```